# Brownie compile - installation of Solc is failing with permission issues (PermissionError: [WinError 5)

Tags: python, solidity, brownie

I am using brownie to compile a .sol file, I am getting the error messages below. I have tried to run with ADMIN on command prompt, I have turned off my Anti Virus , I have checked permissions of the folders below, absolutely run out of ideas on how to resolve.

brownie compile
Downloading from https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/windows-amd64/solc-windows-amd64-v0.6.12+commit.27d51765.zip

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\mcbai\AppData\Local\Temp\solcx-tmp-16508' -> 'C:\Users\mcbai\.solcx\solc-v0.6.12'

Comment: It seems that you don't have permission to run compiler `solc-v0.6.12`. Maybe allow user to run solc compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else having this problem, after many hrs trying to figure this out, turning off my AV resolved this - I hope this helps someone